# how do i change the redirection on youtube embedded movie?

Tags: php, html, properties, youtube, embed

I have embedded a youtube movie in my website:

```
"<object width="300" height="270" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"
"param name="wmode" value="transparent"
"param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com..."
"embed width="300" height="270" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com..." 
wmode="transparent">
"</object>"
```

I want to change the redirection, so when a user clicks on the video he will be redirected to another site and not to youtube.
I tried changing the `src` value but with no luck.

Is that possible?

Comment: No. This is handled internally within the youtube flash player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embedded code loads a flash object. Just like an iframe, any content inside this object that is displayed on the screen is coming from the src attribute, and as such you have no direct control over this.

Having said that, your best approach is to ovverride this click event from being triggered on the , by catching the event by its parent object (the wrapper) that you have specified and treat this event yourself:

with jquery:

```
$(".wrapper").click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are loading in remote content, This means that the content is coming from youtube. The simple anwser is no.

you could overwrite an onclick on the object using javascript but im not sure how the broswer will react to it.